# Data Logic Levels Sent From Sensor Are Not Going All The Way Low

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, uart, serial, logic-level

I'm having issues receiving data from a 3.3 volt logic level [R503 Fingerprint Module](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/4651/4651_R503+fingerprint+module+user+manual.pdf) that is sent via it's Tx pin using UART. The logic levels are converted to 5 volts using a bi-directional converter. When not plugged into the converter, the logic levels from the module are 2.6 volts in the high state and 0 volts in the low state (See image 1). When the sensor is connected to the converter, the logic levels from the module, measured on the low side of the converter, are 2.6 volts in the high state and 1.2 volts low state (See image 2). This results in the output from the converter to NOT be driven all the way low, therefore preventing the microcontroller from receiving any data. See image 3 for output from the level converter.

I am unable to determine the cause of this issue.  I have checked and used different cables, connectors, and power supplies. This issues is also present and can be reproduced on the only 2 sensors I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Image 1: 1 volt/div - Tx pin Not connected level converter

[image]

Image 2: 1 volt/div - Tx pin connected to level converter. Measurement is taken at the low side of the converter.

[image]

Image 3: 2 volts/div - Tx pin connected to level converter. Measurement is taken at the high side of the converter.

[image]

**EDIT: Added schematic**

[image]

Comment: I think you need to share the schematic and the datasheet for the logic level converter.

Comment: Where did you connect it? And how? What modules and boards were used? Links and schematics?

Comment: Link to the level converter: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07LG646VS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: We don't need a link to the vendor's page for the level converter, we need **you** to add the **schematic** of your system to **this question**.

Comment: Are you sure the sensor TX output is connected (via level shifter) to MCU RX input?

Comment: @Wallace, we get many questions with links to an Amazon advert when we need a link to a datasheet. There's a reason why these parts are so cheap: no supporting documentation - and we're not their tech support department. Can you provide a schematic for the board?

Comment: Ok, I added a schematic of how its connected. Sorry for the crudeness. Thank you all for your assistance.  I will now try to find more info on the logic converter.

Comment: Check all  Gnds with an ohmmeter wrt USB shield

Comment: I just ordered a different level converter from digikey.  I'm going to try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @Wallace - Hi, The schematic on the last page of the R503 module datasheet seems to be aimed at a slightly different sensor. However, it shows "VT" on pin 6 should have a permanent power supply (even if the main power to pin 1 is switched on by an MCU only when a touch is detected). That suggests that pin 6 powers part of the sensor. Your diagram shows you are not supplying power to VT, so part of the sensor might be unpowered. Please supply 3.3V to pin 6 also & re-test. It is interesting that the "logic high" output voltage you measure (with no load) is 2.6V which is 0.7V lower than expected.

Comment: @SamGibson - There is no change with it connected or not.  I find it curious also that the voltage is 0.7 volts less than the 3.3 expected.  I contacted the manufacture to asking if this is typical, but no response yet.

Comment: @Wallace - (a) Thanks. Based on that result and more background research, I therefore *suspect* that pin 6 only powers the touch functionality which can raise the signal on pin 5 (called WAKEUP or TOUCH etc). (b) The 0.7V difference between the logic high on TX (2.6V) and the power rail (3.3V) is interesting as that's a classic "diode drop" voltage. I assume the PCB on your sensor is "potted" (as I see on various online photos) so you (and us readers) can't investigate anything about the circuitry ourselves. || Anyway, no further reply needed, I just wanted to add that info. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

That board you linked is an I2C level shifter.

I2C buses all have pullup resistors.  Often in the low kiloOhms range.  I suspect the pullup resistors are simply overwhelming the sensor trying to pull down to ground.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have a logic level converter that you would recommend? Or should I try something like using an opamp as a buffer?

Comment: The sensor to the Arduino line is 3.3V but the levels are enough to trigger the the Arduino, so you don't need to shift it.  You only need to level shift the line coming from the Arduino to the sensor.  In this application, be simple--feed that line to two resistors configured as a voltage divider.  I really suggest searching stackexchange and the arduino forums for voltage translation.  There are a *LOT* of articles written about this.

Comment: I've already tried connecting the modules Tx line directly to the Arduino with no luck. I even tried to buffer the Tx line with an opamp and it still has the same issue. I think I must have bought a couple of faulty sensors.